# Availability of big files on multiple servers

Tags: linux, debian, load-balancing, distributed-filesystems

I have to handle many (1'000 - 30'000) big files ranging from 200MB up to 2GB. The demand for these files is variable (0 - 300 downloads / file). This is why a single file must saved on 2 or more servers.

My servers are placed in different datacenters (France), with different size HDDs (750GB to 4TB).

Currently I share the files using PHP and ncftpget / ncftpput, but it's very slow.

I need a solution to handle balancing these files across 7+ servers.

Example:
File A: 300 downloads/day
File B: 100 downloads/day
File C: 1 download/day

Every file is saved on a different server.
File A has a "high demand" and must copied to another Server.

> "high demand" = Many users want this file...

Comment: What OS are they hosted on?

Comment: Thats all Debian Server.

Comment: 300 downloads a day is not high demand.

Comment: it´s a example for one file ;) We host 2.000 or more files

Answer (score 1):

I'd use something like DRBD if you need real-time replication, or rsync in a cron from a master server if you don't need real-time mirroring.

Comment: i dont want to sync alls my servers. I want to save different files on the servers, but files with a high demand should be on multiple server.

Comment: That's really unclear. You should edit your question and define things like "high demand".

Comment: Sorry :) "high demand" = many users want do download a single file.  

Example: File A: 300 downloads per day // File B: 100 downloads per day // File C: 1 download per Day.

File A need to share on 2 or more server